# Creepy user digs my old questions and downvotes them once a day

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, behavior, code-of-conduct

There is a creepy user who answered my question on Stack Overflow that I haven't accepted the answer with. He then keeps leaving a comment for like three consecutive days, asking for updates on his answer (which I interpret as basically asking me to accept his answer already). He also edits my old questions several times which I assume he is doing to get my attention. Well, he did.

My reputation count has been silent over the years with only occasional upvotes from old questions. Now ever since this creepy user started nagging me, my old questions suddenly gets a downvote once a day straight for a whole week now.

The thing is I've been here On Stack Overflow for 8+ years, and I've never encountered this. My silent reputation count suddenly getting downvotes along side with him nagging me makes me suspicious that it's probably his doing.

I understand that similar downvote attacks has been reported and systems are in place to detect this, but I think this creepy user could be deliberately doing it once a day at different times as to not trigger any alarms or he may even be using dummy accounts. Is there a way we can manually check on this?

Comment: Just flag your post for mod attention and explain the pattern/behavior. Not much the meta crowd can do about this.

Comment: @rene Ok do I just flagged all the old posts with suspicious down-votes?

Comment: One post is enough with links to one or two similar examples, preferable ones that had/have comments from said user. Mention in the custom flag that it is a *recurring pattern/behavior*, that should put mods in the right mode to investigate beyond the post you flag.

Comment: @rene Got it thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that mods often have to defer voting investigation to SE staff. That might either make that your flags takes a bit more processing time or might get marked helpful without anything obvious happening. Allow for 6 to 8 something.

Comment: [a downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308502/839601)